# How to insert/update accented special characters in laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to insert / update accented special characters through Laravel

like

> çã, á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ

and many more.

But laravel is converting into some hex code and insert it into database. Which in return, i am getting content in chinese...

For example:- 
**i am trying to this**

[image]

**Actual query runs in laravel**

[image]

**What shown in blade is**

[image]

I am using SQL-Server-2008

Data type of column is `nvarchar` and collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`

So, what i have conclude is, 
this is the laravel issue becuase if run query directly in database by prefixing **N** like

> set 'name' = N'Vishal çã, á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ'

then it works fine.

**How could we acheive this through laravel ?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1):

I write Laravel apps that are used with spanish characters (á,ñ,...). I use utf8_unicode_ci as default colation, utf8 as default characterset, utf8_unicode_ci as table collation and utf8_unicode_ci with utf8 as character set for the varchar columns. Try it.

Comment: actually i am using sql-server-2008, so it doesn't allow `utf8_unicode_ci`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spanish language better use utf8mu_spanish_ci in your conf/database.php